# Get beginning of next quarter from current Date in R

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I am trying to get beginning of next quarter from the current date.

```
library(lubridate)
current_date = Sys.Date()
quarter(Sys.Date(), with_year= TRUE)
```

or from the function  `quarters.Date(Sys.Date())`I could get quarter. I could not add quarter to the above code .

Are there are any other packages I can use or any other function in the default packages to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) zoo** Convert to `"yearqtr"` class, add 1/4 and if you want the date at the end of the quarter apply `as.Date` using `frac = 1`

```
library(zoo)

today <- Sys.Date()  # 2016-01-27
as.Date(as.yearqtr(today) + 1/4, frac = 1)
## [1] "2016-06-30"
```

Omit `frac=1` if you want the start of the quarter.  Omit `as.Date` if you want the `"yearqtr"` object:

```
as.yearqtr(today) + 1/4
[1] "2016 Q2"
```

**2) base of R**.  This will give the beginning date of the next quarter with no packages.  We use `cut` to get the beginning of the current quarter, convert to `"Date"` class and add enough days to get to the next quarter and apply `cut` and `as.Date` again:

```
as.Date(cut(as.Date(cut(today, "quarter")) + 100, "quarter"))
## [1] "2016-04-01"
```

If you want the end of the quarter add enough days to get to the second next quarter and subtact 1 day to get to the end of the prior quarter:

```
as.Date(cut(as.Date(cut(today, "quarter")) + 200, "quarter")) - 1
## [1] "2016-06-30"
```

Comment: Thanks @G Grothendieck.. Using above I can get required date and then using quarters.Date() , I can get quarter. Just wondering if we can access year and qtr from yearqtr object?

Comment: If `yq <- as.yearqtr(today)` then `format(yq, "%Y")`, `format(yq, "%q")`, `floor(as.numeric(yq))` and `cycle(yq)` are varous ways.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer does indeed work. If you would like to leverage the lubridate library, you can use the following:

```
ceiling_date(current_date, "quarter")
```

This will return the first date of the next quarter. Other helpful functions that are similar are floor_date and round_date. Both can be found in the lubridate documentation - 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf.

Comment: As @Hangtime79 says, to get ending date of last quarter then `floor_date` will get you the start of this quarter, then subtract a day to get last day of prior quarter i.e. `lubridate::floor_date(current_date, "quarter") - 1`.  If current date was 31 Oct 2020 then this would return 30 Sept 2020.